# Stored procedures - identifying the result of execution (not manually)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to make an overview of stored procedures - whether they are just reporting procedures with select statement as a result or if they do modification of data in tables.

Is it possible to get this information without searching the procedure syntax in every case ? Do you have any ideas ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [DatabaseName]
SELECT [name] AS ObjectName, [Type] AS ObjectType
FROM Sys.Objects
WHERE [Type] in ('P')
```

This gets all SQL Stored Procedures in the specified database.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a question of searching by the procedure code. you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
o.Object_id 
, o.TYPE_DESC Object_type
, ORIGINAL_DB_NAME() Database_name
, SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) Schema_name
, o.name Object_name
, ORIGINAL_DB_NAME() + '.' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.name 
Object_fullname
FROM syscomments c INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.id = o.object_id
WHERE 
c.text like '%search_expression%'
```